# layered css - how to limit the background on a second layer

Tags: html, css

http://fiddle.jshell.net/v5sc9/

I'm trying to end the white about 10px before the end of the right side of the page. I've tried a couple of things, but I'm not sure how to make this work because of the layers. Help?

Answer (score 0):

No need to make it complicated:

On the overlay:

```
margin-right: 20px
```

20px instead of 10px due to the 10px offset on the left side.

Codewise, removing `left: 10px` and `margin-right: 20px` replacing it with `margin: 0 10px` will look nicer.

Answer (score 0):

```
#background {
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;

}
#overlay {
    position:relative;
    top:-100px;
    margin-right:20px;
    left:10px;
    z-index:10;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
}​
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do it with percentage based "width" and "left".
I've modified your example, the container now has equal margins (not 10px tough):

http://fiddle.jshell.net/3bbg8/